# Почему функция is_palindrome не видит метода .lower()?

Tags: python

Если вводить слово с большой буквы - ответ "False", с маленькой - все ок:

```
def is_palindrome(word):
  reversed_word = word[::-1]
  return word == reversed_word.lower()
print(is_palindrome(word='Xex'))
```

Comment: А word-то вы в нижний регистр не перевели

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По факту вы сравниваете `is_palindrome('Хех')`:

Хех(параметр функции) = хех(перевёрнутая строка, с `lower()`)

Из-за регистра это сравнение даёт False

Вам нужно добавить `lower()` к переменной `word` для сравнения

```
def is_palindrome(word):
  reversed_word = word[::-1]
  return word.lower() == reversed_word.lower()
print(is_palindrome('Алла')) # True
```

Comment: Дважды применять lower() к одному и тому же набору символов избыточно, лучше это сделать один раз `return (word := word.lower())[::-1] == word`

Comment: Согласен с вами, но мне кажется, что автор вопроса новичок, поэтому пытался ему помочь на примере его кода, чтобы понятней было, но вы тоже правы

Comment: Спасибо! Понял.

Comment: @cubinez85 Пожалуйста!Ещё вы можете поставить зелёную галочку у ответа, чтобы остальные могли понять, что это решило вашу проблему

Comment: Я бы поставил галочку, но пока не нашел где(

Comment: Подскажите пож, где ставится зеленая галочка? В " правке" вопроса? В меню? Нигде не нашел

Comment: Слева от моего ответа, там серая галочка, но когда нажмете, станет зелёной :)